# Calculate monthly sum() on pivote table

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have a Google Form. Upon submit following fields are populated:

1. Timestamp
2. Product Description
3. Unit Price
4. Quanitity

I have generated a pivot table from this data, in a Google Spreadsheet. The first column is a timestamp and the second column is the `sum` of Unit Price. All is grouped by the `timestamp`.

I don't want it. I want to show the year-month at column 1 and the total costs on that month. It should be group by that month.

In `SQL` I would run this query:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(`Timestamp`, '%Y-%b'), 
    SUM(`Unit Price`*`Quantity`) 
FROM 
    TABLE1
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`Timestamp`, '%Y-%b')
```

Comment: Can you share a doc with us?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `=text(number,format)` to add a column to your original data set.

You can then use the pivot table to group them by year-month or you can use `=sumif(range,criteria,sum_range)` to calculate the sum based on the data in the new year-month column.